# Return method list of list

Tags: java

I have the following method and I now return the last entry but
how I can send list of annotation ?

**I want to return all the annotation list from the loop**

```
public EList<Annotation> getAnnotation()
{
  EList<Annotation> annotations = null;
  for (Sc currSc : sche)
  {
    for (EntityS entitys : ent)
    {
      // Get annotation
      annotations = entitys.getAnnotations();
    }
  }
  return annotations;
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do and what is the problem?

Comment: `annotations.addAll`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to put all the `Annotation`s together, you need to create a brand new `EList` and then add them all, i.e.

```
public EList<Annotation> getAnnotation()
{
  // Create the new list that will hold ALL the annotations
  EList<Annotation> annotations = new BasicEList<Annotation>();
  for (Sc currSc : sche)
  {
    for (EntityS entitys : ent)
    {
      // Get annotation
      annotations.addAll(entitys.getAnnotations());
    }
  }
  return annotations;
}
```

Comment: when i tried to put EList<Annotation> annotations = new EList<Annotation>(); i got error cannot instantiate the type  EList<Annotation>(); ,any idea?

Comment: Btw I have noticed that i have in the import import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.EList; but the problem still exist.

Comment: @FedorE: Are you using [`org.eclipse.emf.common.util.EList<E>`](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.7.0/org/eclipse/emf/common/util/EList.html) ?

Comment: no because when i pot it I got error ...I tried CRTL+SHIFT+O but the problem still exist...maybe do you think that there another way to solve this issue?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20336/discussion-between-durron597-and-fedore)